# How do test the value of an attribute in a controller instance variable?

Tags: unit-testing, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, instance-variables, minitest

I'm using rails 5 and minitest.  I was wondering, how do I test the value of a field in an instance variable of my controller method.  I realize that if I want to test if the variable is defined, I can do

```
assert_not_nil assigns(:issue)
```

but I'm less clear if I want to test the value of @issue.stop_id .  My controller method is

```
  # GET /issues/new
  def new
    unless user_signed_in?
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
    @issue = Issue.new(stop_onestop_id: params[:stop_id], line_onestop_id: params[:line_id])
  end
```

I'm trying this in my test method

```
  test "get index page" do
    get index_url
    assert_not_nil assigns(:issue)
    assert_equal test_stop_id, @issue.stop.id
    assert_equal test_line_id, @issue.line.id
    assert_response :success
  end
```

but I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError on the line

```
assert_equal test_stop_id, @issue.stop_id
```

in the test method

```
test "logged in should get issues page" do
    sign_in users(:one)
    test_stop_id = 1
    test_line_id = 1
    get new_issue_url, params: {stop_id: test_stop_id, line_id: test_line_id}
    assert_equal test_stop_id, @issue.stop_id
    assert_equal test_line_id, @issue.line_id
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to handle it, but I have noticed that using `assigns(:instance_var_name)` will return the value of the instance variable, so you could test value from that with something like this:

```
issue_var = assigns(:issue)
assert_equal test_stop_id, issue_var.stop_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I stumbled across it today and thought I'd add an answer. The confusion is that `assigns(:issue)` returns the global variable defined in the controller. It doesn't, however, define that same global variable in the test suite. Thus, in the test suite, @issue is nil before the assigns call, and is still nil after it.

No matter, it's straightforward to access an object's associations & methods once you can get it via assigns:

```
assert_equal test_stop_id, assigns(:issue).stop_id
```